# How can I send the output of buttons via MQTT to a broker?

Tags: mqtt, python-3.7

I've only been programming Python for two days. I want to send the output of buttons via MQTT to a broker (and then of course to a subscriber). I have programmed the buttons so far and would like to start the publisher-part now.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Button
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

root = tk.Tk()

root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.bind('<Escape>',lambda e: root.destroy())

a=0

def close_window():
    root.destroy()

def callback():
    print ("1")
    a=1

def callback1():
    print ("2")
    a=2

def callback2():
    print ("3")
    a=3

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('my.TButton', font=('Helvetica', '70'))

bx = ttk.Button(root, text = "x", style='my.TButton', command = close_window)
bx.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, anchor=tk.N, ipady=60)

c = Button(root, text="", height=15)
c.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, anchor=tk.N,)

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text="1", style='my.TButton', command=callback)
b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

b2 = ttk.Button(root, text="2", style='my.TButton', command=callback1)
b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

b3 = ttk.Button(root, text="3", style='my.TButton', command=callback2)
b3.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

broker_address="xxxx"

client1 = mqtt.Client("Publisher1")

client1.connect("xxxx")

client1.publish("Button/Number", a, qos=2)

root.mainloop()
```

I want the variable "a" to change with each button stroke, and then be sent 1 time. I have now added the basic publisher script but get many different error messages like:

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused  (Btw, I want to use my Laptop as a broker, I took the local IP address)

and:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied (same story)

I am aware that the Publisher Part will not work, but I don't know what I am missing or what I need to add.

Comment: You don't appear to have tried to add any MQTT code to your example. Read the doc https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/ and have a go, we can then help you fix it

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I tried to add the part as much as I could. I also added how the script should work.

Comment: I would guess that you need to, at least temporarily, disable the firewall on your laptop as it is probably blocking connections.